# Run PHP functions in specific order

Tags: php

I have defined 4 different functions that I need to execute in order

```
function stepOne(){
// Do stuff
}

function stepTwo(){
// Do stuff
}

function stepThree(){
// Do stuff
}

function stepFour(){
// Do stuff
}
```

What's the best practice for this? Thanks!

Comment: Call them from the previous function. 1 calls 2, 2 calls 3, 3 calls 4

Comment: Just call them in the desired order

Comment: Are they assync functions?

Answer (score 0):

```
function stepOne(){
  stepTwo();
  // Do stuff
}

function stepTwo(){
  stepThree();

  // Do stuff
}

function stepThree(){
  stepFour();

  // Do stuff
}

function stepFour(){
// Do stuff
}
```

Once all the declarations are done. You can just call the `stepOne()` which inturn will continue the chain.

```
stepOne(); // which will call stepTwo.
```